# Overwriting least-significant bit in a Word

Tags: haskell, binary

I am trying to write a little tool to hide text in PGM image files by overwriting the LSB in each byte in the input. I need help writing a function such as

```
writeBit :: Bool -> Word8 -> Word8
writeBit b w = ...
```

where the ouput is equal to `w` with its LSB set to `b`. Can anyone help me get started with this?

Thanks

Comment: See the Data.Bits module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [setBit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:setBit) and [clearBit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:clearBit)

```
setBit :: a -> Int -> a
clearBit :: a -> Int -> a
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the right answer, that you should use the module `Data.Bits`, you could also write the function yourself if you only want to set/unset the **least significant bit** of the input byte. Using your function signature:

```
setLSB :: Bool -> Word8 -> Word8
setLSB b w
  | b && even w = w + 1
  | not b && odd w = w - 1
  | otherwise = w
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll echo bmk by saying that Syd Kerckhove's answer is the correct one, but one very short option is

```
setLSB :: Integral n => Bool -> n -> n
setLSB b w = w - 1 + fromEnum b + fromEnum (even w)
```